# Using MediaPlayer with setOnPreparedListener

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer

I'm trying to set an `OnPreparedListener`, but I get this error:

> The method setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener) in the type MediaPlayer is not applicable for the arguments (new OnPreparedListener(){})

`DV` is a global MediaPlayer.

```
String url = "<myurl>";
DV = new MediaPlayer();
DV.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

DV.setDataSource(url);
DV.prepareAsync();

DV.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
     public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
         mp.start();
     }
});
```

Comment: Are you using this code in activity?

Comment: Try Adding `import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;` to your code. Either that or use `new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {...}`

Comment: adding import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener; worked. Can't believe I didn't think of that, thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your code:

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener;
```

Alternatively, you can use:

```
new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {...}
```

> Sourced from [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24274440/error-trying-to-setonpreparedlistener#comment37505568_24274440) by [@Squonk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/488241/squonk)